# How can I play Diablo 3 with a gamepad?

Tags: diablo-iii, pc, controllers

I know it's not supported natively for some reason, but I'd really like to lay back on my couch and enjoy the game in a relaxed position instead of sitting straight up at the table with more keys than I need under one of my hands.

Is there a way to play Diablo 3 with a gamepad?

I'm interested in solutions for any kind of PC-compatible gamepads, so please specify which ones your solution supports.

Comment: It is against the Terms of Service.

Comment: @Assylum where is it written in the ToS specifically? A commenter also says there is no such restriction in the linked question.